# How can I set theme for a fragment programmatically?

Tags: android, fragment, themes

**Description:**

I had been changing my activities themes using **manifests** or, in some cases, when I have to use a personalized theme, programmatically. This is what I was doing:

```
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

I have an activity with switching fragments (*Fragment A* and *Fragment B*). I need to set programmatically **Theme A** to *Fragment A* and **Theme B** to *Fragment B*.

**Problem:**

I've realized that my `setTheme` I use for my activities, is not working for fragments.

I've tried changing the theme in my activity when fragment changes, but this didn't work.

What can I do to solve this?

**Edit:**

**My "father" fragment JAVA code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contenedor_perfil_alumno, container, false);

    viewPagerr = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pagerr);

return view;}
```

Comment: Why did you delete my "thanks for reading" @Nikos ? =(

Comment: Hi Tomas and welcome to Stack Overflow. There were no bad intentions in me editing your post. This is standard policy when editing, to remove salutations, thanks and anything else considered as irrelevant to the problem. It makes it easier for people to focus only on the important information. For more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: Thanks so much for editing, but i am going to keep thanking people for reading my problems. It are only less than 20 characters. Sorry :(

Comment: That's alright! I have never edited a question just to remove a simple thank you; I usually edit formatting and grammar issues first and If there's some added "fluff" as people refer to thanking and salutations here I will remove that as well. It's never personal and never badly intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `inflater` with the theme that you want and use it to inflate the root of fragment.

In your `onCreateView()` method,

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.some_theme))
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, parent, false)
```

For Java,

```
LayoutInflater themedInflater = LayoutInflater.from(new 
ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.some_theme));
View view = themedIinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contenedor_perfil_alumno, container, false);

// ... your other code whatever that is

return view;
```

Comment: What is "val" ??

Comment: It's Kotlin (not Java).

Comment: Thanks you so much @Froyo , but i´ve found some problems. First problem (and the bigest one) is that i´ve defined a "View" wich i use  to inflate my fragment and to find views by id. The other problem i´ve found is that your last code lane has an argument named as "parent" wich my IDE cannot resolve it´s symbol. I have edited my question with my onCreateView`s code. I wish you can help me again :(

Comment: sorry for answering late. I still don´t know how to user your code. Using it means that i won´t be able to find views by id like i am showing in my code. Please help! @Froyo . I have to tell you that my IDE cannot resolve "parent" `s symbol.

Comment: @TomasM I don't know your variable names and stuff. You have to _modify_ your code based on it.

Comment: How would you propose it using viewBinding?